# Ledger Nano S and Ledger Live Desktop not showing XMR

Tags: ledger

On my Ledger nano S are stored both BTC and XMR.

On Ledger Live Desktop I see only the BTC. It's correct?

Why don't I see the Monero wallet also?

Thanks
Giovanni

Comment: What version of Monero are you running? What version of the Ledger app are you running?

Comment: Also, have you installed the Ledger Monero app?

Comment: MONERO GUI 0.14.2

Comment: Ledger 1.5.5  Yes I have installed MONERO APP in the ledger

Comment: @GiovanniSonini - If you still have any issues, let's continue here -> https://monero.stackexchange.com/questions/11303/restore-monero-gui-on-other-desktop